# making colorbar with scientific notation in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting the following heatmap in seaborn. the dataframe is read from the foll. csv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mb3wc8mmis0m7g6/df_trans.csv?dl=0

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df, linewidths=.1, linecolor='gray', cmap=sns.cubehelix_palette(light=1, as_cmap=True))
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=0)
locs, labels = plt.yticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=0)
```

How can I modify the colorbar numbers so that they 160000 shows up as 1.6 with a 10^5 on top of colorbar. I know hot to do this in matplotlib but not in seaborn:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
formatter = tkr.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Comment: What is `tkr`? It would be more helpful to make a MCVE.

Comment: thanks for a great library @mwaskom, `tkr` is `import matplotlib.ticker as tkr`. Adding the dataframe used to construct this plot

Comment: dataframe is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mb3wc8mmis0m7g6/df_trans.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass your `formatter` object  through the `cbar_kws`:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr

formatter = tkr.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(True)
formatter.set_powerlimits((-2, 2))

x = np.exp(np.random.uniform(size=(10, 10)) * 10)
sns.heatmap(x, cbar_kws={"format": formatter})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With seaborn, you can pass the formatter to the colorbar when you create the heatmap through the `cbar_kws` argument.

Using the seaborn documentation as an example...

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
formatter = tkr.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(True)

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12) * 100000000

ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data,
                 cbar_kws={'format':formatter}
                )
```

[image: heatmap with scientific notation colobar]