# How to use scientific notation in Pairplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pairplot

**Is there a way to force scientific notation using Seaborn's Pairplot?** I'm hoping for some consistency between plots (examples below). I've found suggestions for other seaborn plots, but have not successfully implemented anything with Pairplot.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

*Versions:*
seaborn 0.8.1
numpy 1.13.1
matplotlib 2.0.2
pandas 0.23.0

Current plot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#remove NAs
dfna = df.dropna()

#Correlation function
mean = np.zeros(3)
cov = np.random.uniform(.2, .4, (3, 3))
cov += cov.T
cov[np.diag_indices(3)] = 1

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r, _ = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("{:.2f}".format(r),
            xy=(.3, .45), xycoords=ax.transAxes, fontsize = 30)

#2D regression + distribution
p = sns.pairplot(dfna, diag_kind="kde", diag_kws=dict(shade=True, color = "Blue"), plot_kws=dict(s=5, edgecolor="Blue", color = "Blue", linewidth=1))
p.fig.text(0.5, 1.00,'BLAHH', fontsize=30)
p.map_upper(plt.scatter, color = "White", edgecolor = "White")
p.map_upper(corrfunc)
p.fig.text(0.35, -0.04, "xxx", ha ='left', fontsize = 20)
p.fig.text(-0.04, 0.68, "xxx", ha ='left', fontsize = 20, rotation = 90)

#p.savefig('pairplot.svg')
```

Unsuccessful attempts to reformat:

1. ```
   plt.ticklabel_format(style = 'sci')
   ```
2. ```
   import matplotlib.ticker as tkr        
   formatter = tkr.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
   formatter.set_scientific(True)
   p = sns.pairplot(dfna, plot_kws = {'format': formatter})
   ```

Current:
[image: currentplot]

Goal:
[image: goalplot]

Comment: *"I've found suggestions for other seaborn plots"* What are those suggestions?

Comment: Both attempts I listed were based on suggestions for other seaborn plots. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780948/seaborn-matplotlib-how-to-repress-scientific-notation-in-factorplot-y-axis and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418989/making-colorbar-with-scientific-notation-in-seaborn. Also tried to modify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647749/seaborn-showing-scientific-notation-in-heatmap-for-3-digit-numbers

Comment: 29647749 is about heatmap annotations. 35418989 is about heatmap colorbar. 36780948 is helpful but only for a single plot. However it contains two links from which you get the general idea of setting a formatter to an axes. So the remaining problem is to get an axes  `ax` from your pairplot. This is done using e.g. `g.axes[2,0]` for the lower left plot.

Comment: what is the problem with your second solution? It seems to be giving the correct output?

Comment: The second solution is for a different dataset. With the larger values, the axes appear to default to scientific notation. I originally had links stating that the second image was an example of a 'correct plot' but the label seems to have been edited to show the full images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply your formatter to each of the axes created by `pairplot`. actually, the axes on the edge would be sufficient, but it's easier to apply the same thing to all axes equally. I would do:

```
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0,0), axis='both')
```

Comment: helped me a bunch.