# How to show scientific notation

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scientific-notation, relplot

I have a seaborn relplot. I want to show scientific notation. Presently the image takes large space on x and y ticks. I want to minimize it by converting the axis to scientific notation.

My code:

```
sns.relplot(x='Vmpp',y='cVmpp',data=cdf)
```

[image]

My solution and present output:

```
#I tried a solution reported for the seaborn heatmap. It did produce a plot (I think heat plot?) but did not work. 
sns.relplot(x='Vmpp',y='cVmpp',data=cdf,fmt='.2g')
```

Present output:

```
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'fmt'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sns.relplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) is a [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html) function. If you just need the simple scatter plot, you may want to use [`sns.scatterplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot) instead.

In any case, you can fine-tune the plot in the usual matplotlib ways. In particular, scientific notation for any tick label numbers can be forced with [`ax.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='scientific', scilimits=(0, 0))`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html).

I would also recommend setting the `alpha` value, because you have many overlapping points. Here's a complete example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='scientific', scilimits=(0, 0))
sns.scatterplot(x='age', y='fare', data=titanic, alpha=0.5);
```

[image]

**Edit:**
As @mwaskom points out, you can change the tick labels in this way with `sns.relplot()` too, just call the plotting function before the formatter in this case. You don't need to specify the axes, because `ticklabel_format()` works via the `matplotlib.pyplot` interface too:

```py
# [...] imports and data as above 

sns.relplot(x='age', y='fare', data=titanic, alpha=0.5)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='scientific', scilimits=(0, 0));
```

Comment: There's no reason you can't change the format of the ticklabels this way with `relplot`, you just have to do so after plotting rather than before.

Comment: @mwaskom Thanks for pointing this out. I edited the answer accordingly. I love the seaborn library by the way, so thank you for that too.

Comment: @mwaskom Even I was wondering the same. However, I tried both. Surprisingly it worked only with `scatterplot`, not `relplot`. Any reason?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution does not use relplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

g = sns.relplot(x='age', y='fare', data=titanic, alpha=0.5);

for axes in g.axes.flat:
    axes.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='scientific', scilimits=(0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: [A similar answer exists for pairplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50762374/2641825) as well. I'm wondering if there is another seaborn solution that doesn't require looping on axes.