# How to set axis label format to scientific format in seaborn relplot with facets when axes are not shared

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, relplot

I am creating a facet plot with the seaborn library with:

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
g = sns.relplot(data=titanic, x='fare', y='age', col='sex', row='survived', height=2, facet_kws=dict(sharex=False, sharey=False))
g.set_titles(row_template='{row_name}', col_template='{col_name}')
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='scientific', scilimits=(0, 0))
```

[image]

I would like ALL subplots to have scientific notation.

Using Seaborn version 0.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since the axes are not shared, the format can be set by iterating through each axes.
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68202693/7758804) shows how to set the tick label format when x and y are shared.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
g = sns.relplot(data=titanic, x='fare', y='age', col='sex', row='survived',
                height=4, facet_kws=dict(sharex=True, sharey=True))
g.set_titles(row_template='{row_name}', col_template='{col_name}')

# iterate through all the axes
for axes in g.axes.flat:
    axes.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='scientific', scilimits=(0, 0))
```

[image]