# How to display ticks in plain number for seaborn heatmap with logarithmic scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am generating a heatmap using seaborn which has a logarithmic scale. How can I change the colorbar labels from scientific notation to plain number.

```
import math
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
vmax=2
vmin=0.5
center = (vmax+vmin)/2
log_norm = LogNorm(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmin)
cbar_ticks = [0.5, 0.66, 1, 1.5, 2]
ax = sns.heatmap(corr, square=True, mask=mask, cmap=cmap_type, linewidths=.5, vmax=vmax, vmin=vmin, norm=log_norm, cbar_kws={"ticks": cbar_ticks}, center=center)
```

[image: generated graph]

Edit:

The following code fixes the problem with scientific notation:

```py
    import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
    formatter = tkr.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
    formatter.set_scientific(False)
    cbar_kws={"ticks": cbar_ticks, "format": formatter}
```

but `norm=log_norm` is adding additional ticks (Please see image below). How do I remove these?

[image: Updated graph]

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35419495/8881141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following codes helped.

For the first part of the problem adding "format" in cbar_kws parameters helped.  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35419495/8881141):

```py
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
formatter = tkr.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(False)

ax = sns.heatmap(corr, square=True, mask=mask, cmap=cmap_type, linewidths=.5, vmax=vmax, vmin=vmin, norm=log_norm, cbar_kws={"ticks": cbar_ticks, "format": formatter}, center=center)
```

For the second part, which is caused due to a bug in matplotlib, adding the following removes the minor ticks. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65676007/11897903):

```py
ax.collections[0].colorbar.ax.yaxis.set_ticks([], minor=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`seaborn` plots are wrappers around `matplotlib` so I would suggest this

```
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
```